My socket.io server code isn't running when everything else is
I'm going to preface this by saying, I'm not that great at coding, so sorry if my code is bad.

What I'm trying to do is make an socket.io server, but I'm having trouble with the server code not running for some reason. Everything else runs, but not index.js.
Index.html:
<!doctype html>
<html>
        
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Thingie</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
        
  <body>
    <div class="title" id="title">
        Idk
    </div>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
        
</html>


script.js:
const socket = io();

io.on("Hello", (msg) => {
    alert(msg)
});


index.js:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.emit("Hello", "Hi")
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

I have tried following the socket.io tutorial on their website, but that didn't help me very much. I tried adding  to the html hoping that it would run index.js, but that didn't do anything either.

Your code looks correct. How are you running your server code? What command are you using, and what output are you getting?

How is your backend going to deliver the javascript and css files? You have no route accepting those requests ...

@CamdanMead I use Node Index.js to run the code, and when the code runs it Just displays the Idk Text. Another thing worth noting is that the terminal displays the "listening on *3000" code.

@derpirscher notes a great point, you're gonna want to deliver your static files. Might be worthwhile to use express static

As I said: your server can't deliver css and is files to your client. Ie, no js is running at the client (open the browser developer tools and you probably will see a bunch of 404 errors). Add some code to serve those files to the backend
